# How to multiply a constant double value with GpuMat in openCv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCv 2.4.6 Library with VS 2010. I compiled O  Cuda 4.2.9 on mypenCv this Library with Laptop and it works fine. Now i want to multiply 1.5 with cv::GpuMat . So how can i do that using OpenCv 2.4.6 in VS 2010 ? It is easy for cv::Mat. 
Like Example

cv::Mat mat =cv::imread("readImg.tiff",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
cv::GpuMat gpuMat(mat);
cv::Mat newMat=mat*(1+0.5);

now how can i do this mathamatical operation with cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuMat in OpenCv ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `convertTo` method:

```
cv::GpuMat gpuMat(mat);
gpuMat.convertTo(gpuMat, gpuMat.type(), 1.5); // gpuMat = 1.5 * gpuMat
```

Comment: How would one add, subtract, and divide? Using gpuMat?

Comment: @Zypps987 the documentation is pretty spotty, but if you dig into the source, you'll see that `void GpuMat::convertTo(OutputArray dst, int rtype, double alpha, double beta = 0.0)` basically means `alpha * dst + beta`. Of course you can use multiplication for division as well.

Comment: It's been over a year, but I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NVIDIA Performance Primitives (NPP)](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html)

```
//You need to include npp.h
float c[] = {0.25, 0.5, 0.75};
NppiSize ns;
ns.height = src.rows;
ns.width = src.cols;
//for CV_32FC3
nppiMulC_32f_C3R(src.ptr<Npp32f>(), static_cast<int>(src.step), c, dst.ptr<Npp32f>(), static_cast<int>(dst.step), ns);
```

Answer (score 0):

in file： modules/cudaarithm/include/opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp

```
/** @brief Computes a matrix-matrix or matrix-scalar per-element product.

@param src1 First source matrix or scalar.
@param src2 Second source matrix or scalar.
@param dst Destination matrix that has the same size and number of channels as the input array(s).
The depth is defined by dtype or src1 depth.
@param scale Optional scale factor.
@param dtype Optional depth of the output array.
@param stream Stream for the asynchronous version.

@sa multiply
 */
CV_EXPORTS void multiply(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst, double scale = 1, int dtype = -1, Stream& stream = Stream::Null());
```

src1/src2 can be matrix or scalar, that means:

cv::cuda::multiply(cv::Scalar(1.5), gpuMat, gpuMat);